# RAW socket issue about Linux

Tags: linux, raw-sockets

In Linux, I have 2 processes to use 1 eth interface,

process1 is socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))

process2 is socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)

process1 can receive all the package which process2 send/receive, would like to know how does the process1 filter the process2 package

Answer (score 0):

When a sockets protocol is set to ETH_P_ALL, it can handle all the protocols.

[man packet](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html)

Second process is sending udp packets through the same interface which is used by first socket for listening. First socket's protocol is set to ETH_P_ALL, it can see all packets; both incoming and outgoing. All the outgoing packets will have a packet type of PACKET_OUTGOING.